# What is the best mission in gta online to get the most rp and cash after patch 1.11?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I want to rank up and get money quick without or with cheats any ideas? I'm rank 55.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the most effective method of grinding is running a playlist of the mission Coveted.  [Here is a link to a 360 playlist](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/playlists/playlist/_DnH4N1NXE2SdjTm9ocQ5Q)